# A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non fixed width

Tags: java, regex-greedy, single-quotes, negative-lookbehind

I am trying to write condition in look behind to prevent space removing in quotes and after specific keywords.

For example, I have a string str = "client_id like 'TACIENT 1%' or client_id < 'TACLIENT'" ;
Then I use regex: **(?i)(?<!(eq|ne|<|>|like))\s(?!(eq|ne|<|>|like))** and output is:
client_id like 'TACIENT1%'
or
client_id < 'TACLIENT'

But should be without space removing inside quotes:
client_id like 'TACIENT 1%'
or
client_id < 'TACLIENT'

So regex to find text in single quotes is: **'(?:[^']|\.)'*** but when I put this regex in look behind: **(?i)(?<!(eq|ne|<|>|like|'(?:[^']|\.)*'))\s(?!(eq|ne|<|>|like))**** I have an error that: "a quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non fixed width" . When I put '?' after '*' quantifier it also doesn't helps
So is there is any alternative way to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a lookbehind assertion with a quantifier, you can use a capture group to match from `'...'` to "get that out of the way" and then use that capture group in the replacement.

The alternative will match a whitespace char with the assertions to the left and the right.

```
('(?:[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)')|(?<!eq|ne|[<>]|like)\s(?!eq|ne|[<>]|like)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SWeHn5/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/bLnyn3)